# Why most of the devices supported by CyanogenMod are from HTC?

Tags: cyanogenmod

Why most of the [devices supported](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices) by [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com) are from HTC?

Answer (score 11):

Because, for the most part, HTC doesn't try to lock down their phones. Compare this to Motorola: all their phones have locked bootloaders except for the original Droid. However, Motorola has been showing signs that they might be changing this behavior in the future. A lot of the HTC phones can use the Unrevoked method to root their phones (except for maybe the Thunderbolt?).

Comment: And compare to Samsung: Their phones are very accessible, but have a ton of custom drivers. They're pretty hard to integrate into a AOSP-ish ROM.

Comment: Add to this that HTC publish his source code relatively soon after launching a device and the fact that their phones are pretty popular...you'll have the perfect ecosystem for hackers to play with this phones.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, HTC phones have been the easiest to unlock, which directly translates to their hackability and therefore support from community developers.

Allegedly, [newer](http://www.intomobile.com/2011/05/13/htc-sensation-looks-have-locked-bootloader/) [HTC](http://www.talkandroid.com/34418-htc-locks-incredible-s-bootloader-no-custom-roms/) [devices](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/03/18/htc-thunderbolt-takes-a-page-from-motos-playbook-bootloader-is-locked/) are a lot more restricted, which will put a damper on custom ROM availability.  I believe [Samsung](http://androidheadlines.com/2011/04/new-samsung-devices-to-feature-unlocked-bootloaders.html) will soon take the lead in the "most hackable" category, and we'll start seeing more of their handsets on the CM's "supported" list.